# Would it be possible to get a dragon to CR27 using only official material and variants (Shadow Dragon/Dracolich, innate spellcasting, etc.)?

Tags: dnd-5e, cr-calculation

Ancient Gold Dragons and Ancient Red Dragons have a CR of 24. This means that, if you were to have such a dragon of the innate spellcasting dragons variety (MM p.86), they could know spells up to 8th level. I'm wondering if it would be possible to get a dragon up to CR27 (to give it access to 9th-level spells) using only official materials and variant rules.

By my calculations, an Ancient Gold Dragon has a defensive CR of 25 and an offensive CR of either 22 or 23, giving it an average CR of 24. In order to get it up to an average CR of 27, the easiest route would most likely be by raising its OCR, as it has more room for improvement. In order to get it to CR27, its OCR would need to be at least 28. The Ancient Gold Dragon gets a +2 boost to its OCR due to having an exceptionally high attack bonus, meaning its damage output would need to be equivalent to CR26, which is 231-248 damage per round on average over the first three rounds of combat.

As far as I know, making the dragon a Shadow Dragon or Dracolich doesn't significantly increase its damage output. A Shadow Dragon's breath weapon is more lethal due to instantly killing upon dropping a character to 0, but I don't know how to quantify that.

Is there a selection of spells of levels 1-8 that could be given to a dragon in order to get its OCR up to 28? Or is there another way to get a dragon to CR27 that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Is there a specific dragon you want to inflate to that CR, or will any dragon work? Would you consider the incorporation of magic items, class levels, or blessings of some sort a viable modification (all of these options appear in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Gold Dragon would be best, but I'm open to any type. I would like to avoid elements outside of the dragon's innate nature, so no magic items, class levels, or blessings.

Comment: I'm voting to close at Too Broad. Unfortunately, without defined parameters of what you need your build to end up as besides the final CR, there could be too many options without a clear determination of what makes one better. We can't just modify a monster for you without knowing exactly what you're aiming for besides the end result CR.

Comment: @NautArch Would if be sufficiently focused if I limited it to innate spellcasting spell selections to reach CR27? Or even narrower still, spell selections to maximize damage output?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, you may do better hopping into [chat] or posting about it on [meta]. But my hunch is that this is more akin to helping you brew/modify which isn't generally our baileywick.

Comment: I think you may have come up with a different question (which is okay, but you should ask it separately.) It doesn't seem to be about CR at all anymore, but about choosing spells. I'm not 100% certain it's answerable outside of opinions, but I definitely don't think this is the same question and it seems to invalidate the answer below.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask it as a new question. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3):

### The Dungeon Master's Workshop doesn't map to CR perfectly

This is the calculation according to the Dungeon Master's Workshop:

**A gold dragon's defensive CR is 28**. This stems from it's effective HP (adjusted by 90 for its Legendary Resistance) which lands on CR 26, and its effective AC (adjusted by 2 for its Saving Throw proficiencies) is five higher than the suggested for CR 26 bumping it up to 28:

> Now look at the Armor Class suggested for a monster of that challenge rating. If your monster’s AC is at least two points higher or lower than that number, adjust the challenge rating suggested by its hit points up or down by 1 for every 2 points of difference.

**A gold dragon's offensive CR is 22**. This stems from the damage output which lands on CR 19.

A gold dragon's three-round damage output includes 2 bite attacks, 4 claw attacks, 9 tail attacks (wing attacks do slightly less damage if not on more than 2 targets), and 1 breath weapon. On average this places the damage output per round somewhere around 117.

Then, because of the high attack bonus, this is adjusted to 22:

> Now look at the attack bonus suggested for a monster of that challenge rating. If your monster’s attack bonus is at least two points higher or lower than that number, adjust the challenge rating suggested by its damage output up or down by 1 for every 2 points of difference.

---

This gives our ancient gold dragon a CR of 25, while the dragon *actually* has a CR of 24. There is clearly something else going on that we can't account for. As such, using the Workshop to modify this monster will not necessarily yield reliable results for CR.

### High CR Monsters

High CR monsters don't fit in to the CR model very well. The *Monster Manual* was created before the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and as most play takes place in the earlier levels, the system in the Dungeon Master's Workshop was likely designed with a focus on those tiers of play.

**Don't design your tier 4 encounters to CR.** When it comes to high level play, the focus should no longer be on hyper-attention to the exact CR levels to make a balanced encounter. Instead, when player characters reach this upper echelon of power, treat epic combat encounters more like a plot lines in themselves.

This can include creating multi-stage combats, incorporating diverse challenges, and swaths of minions that don't have strict stat blocks, but are treated more like hazards or obstacles (and definitely include actual hazards and obstacles). Not only will this avoid the problems the CR system has in this tier, but in my experience makes for a more enjoyable epic tier.

The reason this is especially important in the epic tier is that mundane party vs monster fights are no longer as meaningful. When in groups where the fights retained the same structure, high level spells and magic items either made these fights negligible (a simple *banishment* or *imprisonment* did the trick), or the GM was forced to create arbitrary restrictions on these types of solutions which felt very immersion breaking.

The times I've enjoyed the epic tier the most (as a player and a GM) is when combating the larger scale threats was more of a mini adventure to itself where banishing the monster wasn't enough, or you had to get through a lot of other obstacles first and the final conflict wasn't the main attraction.

Comment: @NautArch That's not what I meant. The Workshop is just limited in its capacity to reflect CR. I've adjusted the framing

Comment: I think you're overstating the Gold Dragon's Defensive CR due to its Fire Immunity. The DMG (pg. 277) says to apply a multiplier to effective hit points if the creature has three or more resistances and immunities, which the Ancient Gold Dragon does not, and so its DCR would be 27 (as opposed to the 25 I calculated earlier, forgetting Legendary Resistances). So CR24 actually seems to be appropriate after rounding.

Moreover, I appreciate your reply, but it doesn't answer my question, which is how to modify the dragon to bring it up to CR27 for the purposes of getting 9th-level spells.

Comment: @Cacse I missed that line

Comment: @Cacse Even adjusting for that, we get DCR 28 and overall CR of 25

Comment: I don't think there is a single way to modify it that would be compelling for an answer on this site. There are countless ways. As is, my answer is sort of a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843)

Comment: How are you getting 28? When I did the calculation earlier I'm pretty sure I got 27, which would give CR24.5. As to your second point, what about spell selections to bring its OCR up to CR27, giving it an average CR of 27?